# magnetic shield for spacecraft outside of Earths shield

Tags: astrophysics

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a strong enough onboard magnetic field, similar to Earths' that would protect deep space spacecrafts from the solar wind?

Comment: What counts as "deep space"? If its deep enough, you wouldn't really even need to protect yourself.

Comment: Is this possibly a space exploration question?

Comment: Sure it is.  Whether it's reasonable from a cost/mass perspective is another question.

Comment: Discussed by Eugene Parker in this Sci Am article:https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/shielding-space-travelers/

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214771/59023